# How do I get an image on an @Html.RadioButtonFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

If a have:

```
<radio class="js-payment-method js-debit-card" type="button" title="Credit/Debit Card"><img src="~/_common/img/payment-options/card.png"><span>Credit / Debit Card</span></radio>
```

I get my desired result. However, I need to attach this to my model. so starting with:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.PaymentMethodSelected, Enums.PaymentMethod.Card, new { @class = "radio__input js-payment-method", @type = "button", @title="Credit/Debit Card" })
```

How do I modify this to get my image and span in there?

Using @the_lotus suggestion below, the code renders as :

```
<label class="js-payment-method js-debit-card" type="button" title="Credit/Debit Card">
    <input checked="checked" class="js-payment-method" data-val="true" data-val-required="The PaymentMethodSelected field is required." id="PaymentMethodSelected" name="PaymentMethodSelected" type="button" value="Card"> 
   <img src="/_common/img/payment-options/card.png">
   <span>Credit / Debit Card</span>
</label>
```

So the issue now is that the value 'card' from the input element gets displayed because it is a type="button" if I set it to type radio, then the value goes, but I get a radio button instead. I dont want the value to display, but it's required for when the model is posted back to the server

Comment: There is no such thing as a `radio` element in HTML. If you're using some kind of framework which adds that element, please let us know what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RadioButtonFor doesn't generate a <radio> tag but instead a <input type="radio"> tag.

Maybe look at using labels instead.

```
<label class="js-payment-method js-debit-card" type="button" title="Credit/Debit Card">@Html.RadioButtonFor(...) <img src="~/_common/img/payment-options/card.png"><span>Credit / Debit Card</span></label>
```

Comment: This nearly works. for some reason, in the `@Html.RadioButtonFor` the value='card' that gets generated displays 'card' on the screen as opposed to just holding the value in the code behind

Answer (score 0):

if you want to nest an img tag inside a span and radio element.  I would rather do a foreach and write out the html.

In order for the radio buttons to function as a group the name properties need to be the same.  The ID's and values can be different.

```
@foreach(var x in model){
    <input type="radio" name="rad1" Value="@x.PaymentMethodSelected">
    <label>@x.PaymentMethod.Card</label>
    <img src="~/_common/img/payment-options/card.png"><!-- you can pass this uri from the model also-->
}
```